# Intel TBB for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, tbb

Just wondering if there are any multi-threading libraries for Android and iOS.

Also, any hack for Intel's TBB to making it run on Android and iOS??

Answer (score 4):

The OpenCV project includes a CMake recipe for building TBB on Android:
http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/branches/2.4/opencv/3rdparty/tbb/CMakeLists.txt.

The ACM Queue just published a paper from some NVIDIA and OpenCV researchers that includes data running OpenCV using TBB on an ARM Tegra 3 platform, so it's at least possible to use TBB for high-performance use: http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2206309.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the only information I found is this :

> Hello, actually our initial version is just a hack. We simply
>   commented all the platform specific code and get TBB compiled for
>   Android. But it was not functional. Currently, after you message about
>   GCC generics, we decided to try to use them. Finally we get TBB
>   compiled. Even a small TBB sample runs successfully on multicore ARM.
>   BUT TBB can't create several threads and it has been linked
>   statically, because we have some problems with dynamic linkage. So, we
>   want to solve these issues with threads creation and linkage. Than, in
>   the case of success, we will send you a patch.

source : http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=79566

So there is no official support, but it seems possible. However, no trace on google about Intel saying they plan to target Android and IOS. Too bad. But I guess they will have to do it anyway some day.

Comment: What are thoughts on http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showpost.php?p=145743 ?  It sounds like in the future any GCC platform will work...

Comment: See the answer from @James - Intel has published Android build instructions.

Comment: For all that have no access to deleted answers, James' link was: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/android-tutorial-writing-a-multithreaded-application-using-intel-threading-building-blocks